# No change in IP address after connecting to VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I joined [lab.pentestit.ru](https://lab.pentestit.ru) to learn pentesting(I'm new to these type of things) and the site gave me a ".conf" file with a username and a password to connect to their VPN using openVPN. To test my connection to VPN they asked me to ping 192.168.101.1.

I noted my public IP address before getting connected and was surprised to notice that it remain unchanged even after I connected to VPN. At first I thought that I'm not connected and there must be some error during connection but pinging 192.168.101.1 worked and it cannot be a machine on my LAN because I've configured my router to provide IP addresses ranging only from 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.199. I'm more certain that I was connected because after disconnecting, the ping requests received no replies.

I want to know why didn't I see any change in my IP address and how does this kind of VPN(in which no IP address change is noticed) work.

Comment: This sound like they gave you access to their internal network by using a VPN. This does not mean that all your traffic is routed then over this network but only that the traffic specific for this network is routed there. Just imagine the VPN as an additional (virtual) network card which is connected to their internal network - all traffic not for this network is still sent over your primary network card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VPN isn't always ment to anonymize your internet traffic and hide your IP. A VPN virtually connects two networks to eachother so they can interact with eachother. For example, you can connect to a PC on the VPN side's LAN, from your own LAN. Some VPN's do hide your IP, but they are configured in a different way.